# Unable to grant external access to published web app

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-drive-api, publish, google-workspace

I'm working on Web App using Google App Script. I'm a Google Apps reseller and would like to be able to share my Web App with other Google Apps users that I sign up.

The web app is currently stored in my Drive. When I *deploy the app* the only options I have available under *Who has access to the app* are

1. Only myself
2. Anyone within my domain

I've gone into my Google Apps domain management and set Drive permissions so that users can share documents outside this organization. I've also tried to share the script from Google Drive and the Google Apps Script interface, but the only sharing options are:

1. within my domain
2. people within my domain with the link
3. private

I've also tried explicitly sharing the script (can view) with an email address of a Google Apps user, on another domain, but I get a *Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist.* error. You can probably see the result by trying to view the web app at this [url](https://script.google.com/a/macros/charliemurder.com/s/AKfycbyz9Rcy-M89TAaQBdZc7nmLiVKGJ7NecYMUWwBPG4_C3MVHmQEd/exec)

The only other cause I can think of is that I registered my Google Apps account when Google still gave 50 free user accounts per domain.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response from Google:

> Regarding your question about Standard accounts sharing Drive files
>   with the public, I've checked with our Drive team and they've
>   confirmed that this is the case. You can share with specific external
>   accounts but not the public. You would need to upgrade to a Business
>   account if you're interested in this feature. For more information
>   about upgrading, please visit
>   http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60217 on our
>   support site.

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into this problem once. On a domain account, not being able to share a script externally. Then, I went to the Domain Settings and changed it. And it still did not allowed me. I found out later that the change in the Domain Settings does not update existing scripts. But when you **create new scripts**, the option to share externally will appear.

Can you please try creating a new script and check the sharing options when deploying it?

Comment: Nope. Same behaviour. I'm unable to make any file in Drive public and since the script is stored in Drive, it's inheriting the permissions. Do you think it's because I have a free Google Apps account?

Comment: Yes, I think this issue only happens with Apps accounts. I don't believe on Google's answers that you need a Business account for this. I think you just have to play around with your domain settings, I remember it's not an obvious setting. Then, remember to always test if it worked by creating a new script. You never be able to deploy publicly existing scripts.

Comment: I've upgraded to a Business Account and lo & behold I got an additional checkbox within my Google Apps Domain management, under Drive settings, reading *Allow users to publish documents on the web or make them visible to the world as public or unlisted documents.*. 
Once checked, there is a bit of a waiting period, but this morning, when I tried to share my drive files, I had two additional options, *public on the web* and *anyone with the link*.

I also republished my Google Apps script and am now able to share it with anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this is useful. The link is under Google Apps>Drive>Settings>Sharing Settings (On and check "Allow users in {your organization} to publish files on the web or make them visible to the world as public or unlisted files.

Best,

Dawn